# System.TimeSpan.Parse parsing incorrectly for HH:MM:SS where HH >= 24

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

When parsing a string of the format HH:MM:SS where HH is greater than 24, this seems to parse the time span incorrectly:

```
[MultiTenant\Exchange\] PS C:\Users\vijara> [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("24:00:00")


Days              : 24
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 20736000000000
TotalDays         : 24
TotalHours        : 576
TotalMinutes      : 34560
TotalSeconds      : 2073600
TotalMilliseconds : 2073600000
```

This is the case for any value of HH above 23.

```
[MultiTenant\Exchange\] PS C:\Users\vijara> [System.TimeSpan]::Parse("45:00:00")


Days              : 45
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 38880000000000
TotalDays         : 45
TotalHours        : 1080
TotalMinutes      : 64800
TotalSeconds      : 3888000
TotalMilliseconds : 3888000000
```

Comment: Explanation is right in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What's your question? It's doing what it was specified to do.

Comment: Consider using `ParseExact` and specifying the format string.

Comment: I believe you would want `[System.TimeSpan]::Parse("1.0:00:00")` to get a 24-hour timespan, and `[System.TimeSpan]::Parse("1.21:00:00")` for 45 hours, in the powershell format.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why this doesn't result in an overflow. But I guess it's dropping the second and parsing the first literal as days when it's greater than the number of hours in a day

Answer (score 0):

Because a day cannot have more than 24 hours.  Once the parsing method see the number larger than 24, it assumes you want days.

[image: Same with different values for demo purpose]